# getting videos in google drive (and Microsoft onedrive) to show in a video tag?

Tags: google-drive-api, onedrive, html5-video

I have a website that has a web page with a html5 video-tag, and the user can supply a URL, and it will play in the video-tag.

The webpage uses JavaScript commands that control the video-tag - for instance, it can pause the video, move to a different point in the video, etc.

It works fine with the cloud.  Videos stored on Microsoft Azure can be used, for instance (Azure gives you a way to get a URL to any video on your cloud storage, and streams it too).

However, I have users that store videos on **Google-drive**, and also on **Microsoft One-Drive**.

From what I can see, I can play these videos, but only in a page (probably with Google's own player in it) on their site.

It seems that there is no way to get a URL to these videos that I can put in a video tag.

Without the ability to do that, I can't use the javascript commands that work with the html5 video-tag.

Is there any workaround?

Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For playing videos that are stored in google-drive using your app:

- you need oauth2 credentials to access the user's drive, but assuming you have the oauth part covered :
- you can create a drive application as a google appengine app and deploy it in a part of your website.
- enable the drive-sdk and set the [open-url](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk) to your website (that you have [verified](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en))
  -> basically this tells drive to redirect towards your website whenever the user clicks on the video (from his drive)
- when drive redirects to your website a [json](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open) file will be sent, you'll have informations such as fileId from there i think you can execute the method files().get() to retrieve the necessary information for you to play the video

I advise you to take a look at this [course](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-drive) in codeschool.